# I need help with this sentence from Re:zero

Tags: words

I'm reading the Re:zero light novel, volume 9. The second sentence in the book is

> 水の中を漂うような、上下左右も曖昧な世界に投げ込まれている

What is 水の中を漂うような modifying? 
And I don't understand the meaning of 上下左右.

Answer (score 2):

- 水の中を漂うような modifies 世界. → "the world where I feel like drifting in water"
- 上下左右【じょうげさゆう】 is simply "上下や左右" or "up, down, right and left." → "the world where even (the distinction between) up, down, right and left is vague"

Answer (score 1):

> 水の中を漂うような、上下左右も曖昧な世界に投げ込まれている

**水の中を漂うような** *like drifting in the water*" is a metaphorical expression close to the astronaut's "**無｛む｝重力｛じゅうりょく｝の空中｛くうちゅう｝に漂うような** *like drifting in the air/sky of weightlessness*", where you cant't distiguish the 360-degree direction.

**上下左右** is a set phrase that describes every direction, all directions or 360-degree direction.
So **上下左右も曖昧な** means *ambiguous in 360-degree directions*.

**世界に投げ込まれている** is （誰｛だれ｝かが/何｛なに｝かが）世界に投げ込まれている, which means  *(Somebody/something) is thrown into the world*.

> What is 水の中を漂うような modifying?

There are three possible answers as:

Answer 1. （水の中を漂うような＋上下左右も曖昧な） → **世界**に投げ込まれている
Answer 2. （水の中を漂うような＋上下左右も） → **曖昧な**世界に投げ込まれている
Answer 3. （水の中を漂うような→**上下左右も曖昧な**）→ 世界に投げ込まれている

I think this is not a question of Japanese but depends on how the reader, you or me, interprets the given sentence.

Answer 1 is "水の中を漂うような" modifies "世界" in parallel with "上下左右も曖昧な". I choose this one.

Answer 2 is "水の中を漂うような" modifies "曖昧 *ambiguous*" in parallel with "上下左右". "水の中を漂うような曖昧な世界" makes sense and is relatively natural. In truth, I would like to change my former answer for this one if the phrase were "水の中を漂うよう**に**" which is grammatically correct.

Answer 3 is that "水の中を漂うような" modifies "上下左右も曖昧な" to make the figurative expression of "上下左右も曖昧な" more concretely imagined by writing another expression similar to it.

As I said before, I do not think there is a fixed answer. Which one do you choose?

Comment: I would say that the comma forces Answer 1. If the comma were not here then Answer 2 and 3 would be possible too.

Comment: answer 2と3は、(形容動詞的な句の)連体形が他の形容動詞を修飾する、と仰っているのですか？ 「すごいハンサムな」のような非標準の例外を除けば、通常そんなことは起こらないと思いますが。

Comment: あと「上下左右も曖昧だ」という表現は、上下左右の方向の区別自体が不明瞭な、無重力空間的な状態を述べているのであって、「(どちらが上か下かは分かってるけど)どの方向を向いても何かが曖昧だ」と言っているのではありませんよね。

Comment: @naruto:次のような３つの解釈があるなと思って回答しましたが文法的な解釈で拙いところは多々あると思います。
（１）水中を漂うような世界　言いかえれば　上下左右も曖昧な世界
（２）水中を漂うような曖昧な世界　言いかえれば　上下左右も曖昧な世界
（３）水中を漂うような　言いかえれば　上下左右もわからないような曖昧な世界

＊＊＊「上下左右曖昧」とはどこは既知でどこが未知かほど厳密には考えておりませんが、どっち方向もわからないような意味かと思っていました。

Comment: 単に「～な」は連体形だから必ず名詞(句)を修飾する、という初歩的な話です。「色々な簡単な問題」という言葉があった場合、「`色々な`と`簡単な`が独立して`問題`という名詞を修飾している」と「`色々な`が`簡単な問題`という名詞句を入れ子状に修飾している」という2つの解釈はあり得ますが、「`色々な`が`簡単`を修飾している」と言う解釈はあり得ません。「非常に簡単だ」とは言えても「非常な簡単だ」という文はあり得ませんよね。